# Physical presence of Krishna at multiple places at same time

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana

The [following](https://innerschool.org/spb/sb/10/59/en1) slokas from [Srimad Bhagavatam](https://innerschool.org/spb/sb/en1) indirectly says that Krishna is present at multiple places at the same time

> SB 10.59.43: **The Lord, performer of the inconceivable, constantly
> remained in each of His queens' palaces, which were unequaled and
> unexcelled by any other residence. There, although fully satisfied
> within Himself, He enjoyed with His pleasing wives, and like an
> ordinary husband He carried out His household duties**.
>
> SB 10.59.44: Thus those women obtained as their husband the husband of
> the goddess of fortune, although even great gods like Brahma do
> not know how to approach Him. With ever-increasing pleasure they
> experienced loving attraction for Him, exchanged smiling glances with
> Him and reciprocated with Him in ever-fresh intimacy, replete with
> joking and feminine shyness.
>
> SB 10.59.45: Although the Supreme Lord's queens each had hundreds of
> maidservants, they chose to personally serve the Lord by approaching
> Him humbly, offering Him a seat, worshiping Him with excellent
> paraphernalia, bathing and massaging His feet, giving Him pan to chew,
> fanning Him, anointing Him with fragrant sandalwood paste, adorning
> Him with flower garlands, dressing His hair, arranging His bed,
> bathing Him, and presenting Him with various gifts.

Similarly, are there any other slokas from **the same text(Srimad Bhaghavatham)** that directly says that the phenomena of Krishna's presence at multiple places at the same time?

Comment: Krishna is present everywhere in same time not just at multiple places. Even this comment is typed by Krishna with my body as mere instrument!

Comment: Is multiple Krishnas at same place considered?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta yeah...........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) » **10.13**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/13) also mention Lord Krishna's physical presence at multiple places.

When Lord Brahma took away all the cowherd boys and calves to show some of his own power and see the power of Lord Krishna:

> SB 10.13.19 — By His Vāsudeva feature, Kṛṣṇa simultaneously expanded Himself into the exact number of missing cowherd boys and calves, with their exact bodily features, their particular types of hands, legs and other limbs, their sticks, bugles and flutes, their lunch bags, their particular types of dress and ornaments placed in various ways, their names, ages and forms, and their special activities and characteristics. By expanding Himself in this way, beautiful Kṛṣṇa proved the statement samagra-jagad viṣṇumayam: “Lord Viṣṇu is all-pervading.”
>
> SB 10.13.21 — O Mahārāja Parīkṣit, Kṛṣṇa, who had divided Himself as different calves and also as different cowherd boys, entered different cow sheds as the calves and then different homes as different boys.

After 1 human year (for Lord Brahma this was negligible time as his one day = 1 Kalpa), Lord Brahma visited Vṛndāvana again and could then understand Lord Krishna's potency.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @YDS answer, I would like to add two more incidents, but in this case, multiple Lord Krishnas were present at the same place.

1. [The famous Raas leela](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/33/3/):

In Raas Leela, Lord Krishna expanded Himself in such a way that He was with all the Gopis at the same time and same place.

> The festive rāsa dance commenced, with the gopīs arrayed in a circle. **Lord Kṛṣṇa expanded Himself and entered between each pair of gopīs, and as that master of mystic power placed His arms around their necks, each girl thought He was standing next to her alone.** The gods and their wives were overwhelmed with eagerness to witness the rāsa dance, and they soon crowded the sky with their hundreds of celestial airplanes. (SB 10.33.3)

2. [Lord Krishna weds Nagnajiti](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/58/45/):

There was a king named Nagnajit for the kingdom Koshala. Nagnajit decided to choose a King for his daughter (Satya, or Nagnajiti) but the condition was to defeat his seven sharp-horned bulls. These bulls were uncontrollable. Lord Krishna presented the marriage proposal, King was very happy but as decided he told Krishna that the one who will defeat these bulls would be the husband of his daughter. By accepting King's condition, Lord Krishna expanded Himself into seven, defeated the bulls and married Nagnajiti.

> Upon hearing these terms, the Lord tightened His clothing, **expanded Himself into seven forms and easily subdued the bulls.** (SB 10.58.45)